# How to Dict.get a case insensitive key?

Tags: dictionary, elm

I'd like to grab the `Total-Records` key of a `response.headers` HTTP response.

Problem is that in some browser it is as returned by the server `Total-Records` but in some other, it is in lower case.

I'd like to get the value of the `Total-Records` header regardless of its case.
How would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another alternative is to use the [`find` function from `elm-community/dict-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/dict-extra/2.1.0/Dict-Extra#find) to provide a custom comparison operator:

```elm
import Dict.Extra

caseInsensitiveGet : String -> Dict String v -> Maybe v
caseInsensitiveGet key =
    let
        lowerKey = String.toLower key
    in
        Dict.Extra.find (\k _ -> String.toLower k == lowerKey)
            >> Maybe.map Tuple.second
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the least costly way - in general - is simply to do the two look ups and see what you get. For example,

```
case (Dict.get "Total-Records" response.headers, Dict.get "total-Records" response.headers) of 
    (Just s, _) -> 
         s 
    (_, Just s) ->
         s 
    _ ->
         <handle error case>
```

Alternatively you could replace the above with `if then else`.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of a general-purpose case-insensitive dictionary, you can hack together a manual lookup:

```elm
caseInsensitiveGet : String -> Dict String v -> Maybe v
caseInsensitiveGet key dict =
    let
        lowerKey = String.toLower key
    in
        Dict.toList dict
            |> List.filterMap (\(k, v) ->
                if String.toLower k == lowerKey then
                    Just v
                else
                    Nothing)
            |> List.head
```

Note that this will perform worse the larger the dictionary is. In this form it is possible to have multiple variations of the same text with different cases, so it isn't perfect, but if you're just looking for a header, it should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I think I might go (uses [elm-community/list-extra](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/6.1.0/List-Extra#find)):

```
getFirstCaseInsensitive : String -> Dict String v -> Maybe v
getFirstCaseInsensitive key dict =
    let
        key_ =
            String.toLower key
    in
        dict
            |> Dict.toList
            |> List.Extra.find
                ((==) key_ << String.toLower << Tuple.first)
            |> Maybe.map Tuple.second
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, I ended up using `Dict.Extra.mapKeys`:

```
import Dict.Extra


headers =
       Dict.Extra.mapKeys String.toLower response.headers
```